# VBA insert function in formula bar

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Searchable()
Sheets("test").Select
    Range("C2").Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('Employee and Job List'!    $A:$A,MATCH(ROWS(test!$B$2:$B2),test!B:B,0)),"")"
        Range("C2").Select
            Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C1200")


End Sub
```

I'm trying to get this code to work and I'm getting am application-defined or objective-defined error I have another one just like it that works and then another that does. The only thing different is that the two witht he error start with an if function.

All help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: change `""` to `""""`

Comment: that worked thanks

Comment: if you want to list that as an answer I'll check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `"` inside the string needs to be doubled. Change the `""` to `""""`

You also do not need to select or do the fill. Excel will do the adjustments aromatically.

```
Sub Searchable()
Sheets("test").Range("C2:C1200").Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('Employee and Job List'!$A:$A,MATCH(ROWS(test!$B$2:$B2),test!B:B,0)),"""")"
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you have two many double quotes at the end. Try this

```
Range("C2").Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('Employee and Job List'!$A:$A,MATCH(ROWS(test!$B$2:$B2),test!B:B,0)),)"
```